# REGEX - match words that contain letters repeating next to each other

Tags: php, regex

im looking for a regex that matches words that **repeat a letter(s) more than once and that are next to each other**.

Here's an example:

```
This is an exxxmaple oooonnnnllllyyyyy!
```

By far I havent found anything that can exactly match:

```
exxxmaple and oooonnnnllllyyyyy
```

I need to find it and place them in an array, like this:

```
preg_match_all('/\b(???)\b/', $str, $arr) );
```

Can somebody explain what regexp i have to use?

Comment: What's the expected value of `$arr` afterwards?

Comment: the solution you accepted accepts `apple` as well.Is this intended?

Comment: @vks it's not for english lang. Thank you for you observation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a very simple regex like

```
\S*(\w)(?=\1+)\S*
```

See how the regex matches at http://regex101.com/r/rF3pR7/3

- `\S` matches anything other than a space
- `*` quantifier, zero or more occurance of `\S`
- `(\w)` matches a single character, captures in `\1`
- `(?=\1+)` postive look ahead. Asserts that the captrued character is followed by itsef `\1`
- `+` quantifiers, one or more occurence of the repeated character
- `\S*` matches anything other than space

**EDIT**

If the repeating  must be more than once, a slight modification of the regex would do the trick

```
\S*(\w)(?=\1{2,})\S*
```

for example http://regex101.com/r/rF3pR7/5

Comment: @faq glad to hear it helped

Comment: Does this pattern need / for start and / for end of it? preg_match return error without it!

Comment: @Kermani Yes `preg_match` requires the regex to  be delimited by `/`

Comment: Thank you; But that did not work and I solved my problem by putting ! at the start and the end of pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Use this if you want discard words like `apple` etc .

```
\b\w*(\w)(?=\1\1+)\w*\b
```

or

```
\b(?=[^\s]*(\w)\1\1+)\w+\b
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/20

http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/21

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
\b\w*?(\w)\1{2}\w*
```

The `\w` class and the word-boundary `\b` limit the search to words. Note that the word boundary can be removed, however, it reduces the number of steps to obtain a match (as the lazy quantifier). Note too, that if you are looking for words (in the common meaning), you need to remove the word boundary and to use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `\w`.

`(\w)\1{2}` checks if a repeated character is present. A word character is captured in group 1 and must be followed with the content of the capture group (the backreference `\1`).